# post image or status with facebook page with api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

since yesterday i try to post a status with image (or not) with a facebook page with facebook graph api.

client is connected with this scope :

> email, public_profile, manage_pages, user_posts, publish_actions, publish_pages

i call this function

```
    postPicture = () => {
        FB.api("/231713458314438/feed",
                "POST", 
                {
                    "link": "http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/17A21/production/_85310869_85310700.jpg",
                    "message": "test"
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                }
        );
    }
```

publication is published but with my personnal account ON page and not in Admin with page.

So have you an idea to how published a status with page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/

You would also need to pass the `access_token` generated for the logged in admin as a paremeter request:

```
postPicture = () => {
    FB.api("/231713458314438/feed",
            "POST", 
            {
                "link": "http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/17A21/production/_85310869_85310700.jpg",
                "message": "test",
                "access_token": {your-access-token}
            },
            function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello, it did the same thing , this post publication with my account on the page and not the page

Comment: then the access token you have is from your account, make sure you logout from browser, login through the application with account you need to post to and then call this method.

Comment: yes i get access_token when i'm accept application or when i load page who load facebook api, but it does the same result. I would like to publish with page and not with my account...

Answer (score 0):

1. **Get User access token from Facebook Portal**

   - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

     Select "Facebook App": Your App

     Select "User or Page": User Token (Get User Access Token)

     Select Permission: "pages_manage_posts"

     Click copy Access Token:

     - => Short-Lived User Access Token: SLUATOKEN
2. **Get Long-Lived User Access Token**

   - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing#get-a-long-lived-user-access-token

     Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

     Select App -> Setting -> Basic -> Get App ID, App Secret

     ```
     curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/oauth/access_token?  
         grant_type=fb_exchange_token&          
         client_id={app-id}&
         client_secret={app-secret}&
         fb_exchange_token={Short-Lived User Access Token}"
     ```

     => CURL:

     ```
     curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=APPID&client_secret=APPSECRET&fb_exchange_token=SLUATOKEN"
     ```

     - => Got Long-Lived User Access Token:        LONGLIVEDUATOKEN
3. **Get User ID**

   - User ID is required in Step 4

     ```
     curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me?fields=id%2Cname&access_token={Long-Live User Access Token}"
     ```

     => CURL:

     ```
     curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me?fields=id%2Cname&access_token=LONGLIVEDUATOKEN"
     ```

     - => Got User ID: YOURFBID
4. **Get Long-Lived Page token**

   - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing#get-a-long-lived-page-access-token

     ```
     curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/{user-id}/accounts?access_token={Long-Lived User Access Token}"
     ```

     => CURL:

     ```
     curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/YOURFBID/accounts?access_token=LONGLIVEDUATOKEN"
     ```

     - => Got Long-Lived Page Token:   LONGLIVEDPAGEACCESSTOKEN
5. **Post Status**

   - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/#publish

     => CURL:

     ```
     curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/feed?message=This_Is_My_New_Status&access_token=LONGLIVEDPAGEACCESSTOKEN"
     ```

     - => Done! Check Your Facebook Page
6. **Check Token Expired Time**

   - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/?access_token=LONGLIVEDPAGEACCESSTOKEN&version=v10.0

     - You will see: `Expires: Never`